# OR-relation in Bayesian Networks

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks

How do you represent an OR-relation in a Bayesian Network? For example, P(A | B OR C).

I also wonder how you can calculate the probability for such an expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you taking Stanford's ai-class? :-)

Comment: No, I am studying in Sweden :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not particularly well-posed, because one cannot sum over the conditioned variables in a conditional distribution.  However, an example may help.  If we assume that `B` and `C` are binary variables and introduce a variable `Z = A or B`. Let's define the following joint distribution on `P(A,B,C)`

```
A B C | Z | P(A,B,C) 
------+---+----------
0 0 0 | 0 |   0.02   
0 0 1 | 1 |   0.22   
0 1 0 | 1 |   0.06   
0 1 1 | 1 |   0.08   
1 0 0 | 0 |   0.18   
1 0 1 | 1 |   0.24   
1 1 0 | 1 |   0.17  
1 1 1 | 1 |   0.03
```

Now, by the definition of a conditional distribution, `P(A|Z) = P(A,Z)/P(Z)`.  So, summing up terms

```
P(Z = 0) = 0.02 + 0.18 = 0.20
P(Z = 1) = 0.22 + 0.06 + 0.08 + 0.24 + 0.17 + 0.03 = 0.80
```

and `P(A,Z)`

```
   A | Z | P(A, Z) | P(A | Z)
   --+---+---------+---------
   0 | 0 | 0.02    | 0.10
   1 | 0 | 0.18    | 0.90

   0 | 1 | 0.36    | 0.45
   1 | 1 | 0.44    | 0.55
```

Notice that once we condition on `Z` that the two sets of terms with `Z` held constant both sum to 1.0.

So, in short, there isn't a generic way of calculating `P(A|B or C)`, you need to look at the joint distribution in order to calculate the appropriate probabilities.